# Keep billing info saved in Magento Onepage Checkout Billing step

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, onepage-checkout, billing

Does anyone know the name of the file/plugin that is used to keep billing information saved in the billing form in Magento Onepage checkout? It keeps billing info saved in the form even if the page is refreshed.

I have a custom theme that I need to add this to. I have already copied the billing.phmtl file from the base theme into my theme but it does work as it does in the base theme so I assume it must be done using Javascript.

I would like to know how this is done if someone knows and is happy to share I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The billing address is saved in the quote.

If you look inside `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Billing` you will see how some of the magic happens inside of `billing.phtml`.

Look specifically for the method `getAddress()` as it will show you what and how the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` is returned.

I hope this helps.